# Rake command not working while trying to read email from gmail server using IMAP

Tags: apache, openssl, redmine, bitnami, redmine-plugins

I am running below rake command to read email using IMAP from use_redmine.bat
in which my working directory is \Bitnami\redmine-3.3.3-1\apps\redmine\htdocs>
and the command is

```
rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=imap.gmail.com \
port=993 username=xxxx password=xxxx ssl=1 tracker=feature unknown_user=accept \
allow_override=all --trace
```

Note:
It is working in my local system and I am successfully able to create feature and bug from email conduit. But not working on the server(another system).

Things I have tried:

1. Disabled firewall on the server in case if it is blocking.
2. Disabled antivirus on the server in case if it is blocking.
3. Installed the same setup in both machine local and the server.
4. Installed the same setup with the same windows version.
5. Followed the same setup steps in both machine local and the server like.

   -Installing bitnami-redmine-3.3.3-1-windows-installer.exe.

   -running bundle install.

   -running bundle install --no-deployment.

   -running rake command.
6. Also, have checked that port is listening by net sh command.

   ```
   **Output of the command:**

   ** Invoke redmine:email:receive_imap (first_time)

   ** Invoke environment (first_time)

   ** Execute environment

   ** Execute redmine:email:receive_imap

   rake aborted!

   OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/imap.rb:1492:in `connect'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/imap.rb:1492:in `start_tls_session'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/imap.rb:1085:in `initialize'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/imap.rb:30:in `new'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/imap.rb:30:in `check'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/tasks/email.rake:117:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/mailer.rb:430:in `with_synched_deliveries'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/tasks/email.rake:116:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/bin/rake:22:in `load'
   C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.3-1/ruby/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
   Tasks: TOP => redmine:email:receive_imap
   ```

Any help is so much appreciated.!

Comment: Found that issue is with only google mail server, works with outlook and local smtp.

Comment: Did you solved? in this case, how did you solved it? Thank's a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gmail as the outbound email server and you are not able to send email correctly, Google may be blocking sign-in attempts from your apps or devices. Depending on whether or not you use Google Apps, the steps to correct this will differ:

- [For Google Apps users](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/redmine/#for-google-apps-users)
- [For other Google users](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/redmine/#for-other-google-users)

Comment: You might not have read the question properly mate. Everything working ok on the local machine and all the settings is ok. It is the problem between Google and OpenSSL connection from Virtual Machine.